# Concatenate Field for Duplicate Records for Single Row Result

Tags: sql, duplicates, concatenation

I would like to know how to concatenate a field in my query to return to give me a different end result for the rows I return in my query.

This is what I got:

```
SELECT
     O.OBJECT_ID AS "ID"
    ,A.NAME AS "Full Name"
    ,RECORD.Name AS "Record Type"

FROM 
    OBJECT AS O
    INNER JOIN ACCOUNT AS A ON O.ACCOUNTID = A.ID
    INNER JOIN RECORD ON RECORD.ID = A.RECORDID
```

It Currently Returns the following:

```
ID        FULL NAME     RECORD TYPE
123       John Doe      Website Record
456       John Doe      Website Record
789       John Doe      Website Record
```

This is what I would like it to look like:

```
ID               FULL NAME     RECORD TYPE
123, 456, 789    John Doe      Website Record
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Still haven't found a solution..., anyone?

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate I posted above. your answer will be in there.